# Apache bench の -n に上限値はありますか?

Tags: apache, テスト

CPUに負荷を与えて検証するために以下のコマンドを行おうと思っています。

```
ab -t 60 -c 200 -w test.com
```

ただ先輩エンジニアにこのことを伝えると「abには暗黙的な-nの上限があって、1分もせずに計測が終了してしまうかも」と言われました。
こちらさっとググってみても裏付けはとれず、もしかしたら先輩の覚え違いかも、と思いつつもちゃんとした検証ができないと不安ではあるので、そういった -n の上限値が存在するのかどうかご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、お教えいただけないでしょうか?

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-tを指定するとnは50000の扱いになるそうです。

> -t timelimit
>                 Maximum number of seconds to spend for benchmarking. This implies a -n 50000 internally. Use  this  to  benchmark  the
>                server within a fixed total amount of time. Per default there is no timelimit.

-cはOSの最大のオープン可能なファイルの数を超えることはできません。

Comment: 迅速なご回答ありがとうございます!!
1分で5万リクエストは捌けないので、今の検証の仕方で問題なさそうですね